# How to set your key for GAE Datastore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-datastore

Anyone have an idea why I keep getting this error when I make a `GET` request to `/display-message`? `{ Error: Key path element must not be incomplete: [created_timestamp: ]`. Am I not setting my key the right way? You can view the backend here https://jarvis-hd-live-151521.appspot-preview.com/display-message?last_updated=0

```
const key = datastore.key('created_timestamp', 5689413791121408);

app.post('/message', function (request, response) {
  let message = request.body.Body;
  response.send("<Response><Message>Heyyo!</Message></Response>");

  var d = new Date;
  var time = d.getTime();

  let entity = {
      key: key,
      data: {
        message: message,
        created: time
      }
  };


  datastore.upsert(entity)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Post UPDATED successfully");
    });



});


app.get('/display-message', function(req,res){

    let last_updated_time = req.query.last_updated;     


    function updateMessage(timestamp, message) {
        var output = {
            success: 1,
            data: message,
            timestamp: timestamp
        };

        return res.json(output);
    }

    function checkMessage() {
        console.log("Starting to check message function");
        var timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        datastore.get(key)
            .then((entities) => {
                let entity_data = entities[0];
                console.log(entity_data);

                let message_text = entity_data.message;
                let new_timestamp_value = entity_data.created;

                if(!last_updated_time || last_updated_time < new_timestamp_value) {
                    updateMessage(new_timestamp_value, message_text);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("No new messages at this time");

                    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                        checkMessage();
                    }, 1000 * 10); //10 seconds
                }

            })
            .catch(function(){
                console.log("Promise Rejected");
                console.log(err);
            })
    };

    checkMessage();

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `datastore.key()` is expecting a list:

```
const key = datastore.key(['created_timestamp', 5689413791121408]);
```

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/datastore/0.6.0/datastore?method=key