# How to update entity in Google Cloud Datastore with multiple condition?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to update an entity in Google Cloud Datastore with multiple conditions.

For Example:

```
var data = {status:false};
var postData = await FeedModel.update({id:1234567890,userId:123},data);
```

It is giving the following error:

> [{"status":500,"message":{"code":3,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{}},"details":"Key
>   path element must not be incomplete: [Feed: ]","note":"Exception
>   occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient"}}]

Could you please help me how to update an entity with the multiple conditions?

Comment: The error says "Key path element must not be incomplete: [Feed: ]". Are you sure you specified a complete key? If so, can you share your data model?

Comment: Can you share the code snippet how you are specifying the key? Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41367608/9908267) answer. [This](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/datastore/1.4.x/#using-the-client-library) is how you need to specify.